# Java date-manipulation

Tags: java, date, dayofweek, localdate, date-manipulation

I'm trying to get a date with a Month number, week of month number and a day of week number
I thought this will be easy and did this:

```
LocalDate nextbookingDate = LocalDate.now().plusYears(1);
nextBookingDate = nextBookingDate.with(Month.of(1));
nextBookingDate = nextBookingDate.with(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfMonth(), 1);
nextBookingDate = nextBookingDate.with(DayOfWeek.of(1));
System.out.println(nextBookingDate); //2019-12-30
```

`nextBookingDate`should be 2020-01-06 because its the first Monday in January. 
But why do I get 2019-12-30 and how do I solve this?

Comment: You have not given the complete code, so can't comment on this. But you should have a look at the Joda Time library

Comment: Joda Time has been made obsolete as of Java 8. Of course, for those forced to running on earlier versions, it can still be useful.

Comment: Okay, i changed it.

Comment: You need to decide whether you want the first Monday in January or you want the Monday of ISO week 1 of January. In this case they are not the same Monday.

Comment: Forgot a line sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not completely clear to me what result you want in general, and why. If I may assume that you want the next date that is an *n*th some-day-of-week of some month, it’s a little more complicated than your code. **EDIT:** NorthernSky is correct in [the comment under his/her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59235932/java-date-manipulation/59236160#comment104683957_59235981) that `.with(TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth(1, DayOfWeek.MONDAY))` more directly and briefly gets us what we need. This should work:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Africa/Bamako");
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(zone);
    LocalDate nextBookingDate = today.with(Month.JANUARY)
            .with(TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth(1, DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
    if (nextBookingDate.isBefore(today)) {
        // Take next year instead
        nextBookingDate = today.plusYears(1)
                .with(Month.JANUARY)
                .with(TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth(1, DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
    }

    System.out.println("Next booking date: " + nextBookingDate);
```

Output when I ran the code just now, was:

> Next booking date: 2020-01-06

`TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth()` will get us the 1st Monday, 3rd Tuesday, etc., of the month. So feed any day of week and any number up to 4 or 5 into this method.

Please supply your desired time zone where I put Africa/Bamako since it is never the same date in all time zones.

**Link:** [Documentation of `TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#dayOfWeekInMonth(int,java.time.DayOfWeek)).

Answer (score 2):

In each new line, you are overwriting what you have done in the previous line.
Try something like this:

```
nextBookingDate = now()
   .with(Month.of(1))
   .with(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfMonth(), 1)
   .with(DayOfWeek.of(1));
```

but be aware that December 30, 2019 **is** actually the first day of week 1 of 2020.

Because the question has been updated, a more relevant answer would be:

```
LocalDate nextBookingDate = LocalDate.now().plusYears(1)
   .with(Month.JANUARY)
   .with(TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth(1, DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
```

and you can replace the 1 as argument for dayOfWeekInMonth with a number from 2 through 5 as appropriate.

Comment: Yes i figured that out after more than one hour :D
But how do i get the first monday in January then?

Comment: Look into TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth(DayOfWeek.MONDAY), after first creating a LocalDate in January of the relevant year.

Comment: Yes but the first monday was just for example, what if i want the second monday in january or the third?

Comment: Then you can use TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth with 2 or 3 as the 'ordinal' parameter.

Comment: @NorthernSky You are completely correct, and iit’s a good observation. I took the freedom of stealing that for my answer too, making my code 4 lines shorter. Thank you.